# python del keyword doesn't work on numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, memory, google-colaboratory, del

I tested the two following code snippets in Colab.

The first one is a list of lists.

```
a = []
for i in range(100000):
  a.append([0 for _ in range(10000)])
```

After I run this, the system RAM jumps up from 1.0 GB to 8.8 GB. Then I try to delete this list.

```
del a
```

System RAM gets back to 1.0 GB.

Now I try the same thing with a list of numpy arrays

```
import numpy as np
b = []
for i in range(100000):
  b.append(np.zeros(10000))
```

System RAM jumps up from 1.0 GB to 7.6 GB. But now when I try to delete it:

```
del b
```

Nothing happens!

What's the reason behind this behaviour?
How can I delete `b`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `numpy` is written in C and Fortran.  It does internal memory allocations that are not part of the Python garbage collection rules.  The memory would eventually get reclaimed, but it's not under Python's control.  This could also be a case of heap fragmentation.

Comment: you cannot delete objects in python. In **both cases** above, `del` worked **exactly as it's supposed to**: it removed the name `b` or `a` from the global namespace. `del` does *not delete objects* (python gives you no direct way to do this, it is a memory managed language), it deletes *names*.

Comment: Have you tried calling `gc.collect()` after `del b`?

Comment: @Barmar probably won't affect anything, I see no reason for any reference cycles here

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But unless there's another variable referring to the array, deleting the variable should delete the object.

Comment: @Barmar no, there is no guarantee of that. It so happens in CPython that objects will be reclaimed immediately by the internal heap once their reference counts reach 0, of course, that doesn't mean that the memory is released from the process back to the OS though.

Comment: As @TimRoberts said, the memory for the array is managed in C or Fortran. In C, freeing an allocation doesn't normally return it to the OS, it's kept in the heap for use by future allocations. So your process memory use doesn't go down.

Comment: The way I see it, memory is managed by the OS, the python interpreter, and numpy itself.  Obviously OS supplies memory as needed, especially big blocks. but the others can maintain some sort of 'free space'  that can be 'recycled'.  In other words, especially for small blocks, they don't (have to) return evey bit to the OS.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if it's only about _names_, how is it that in the first case the memory actually gets released? and why it doesn't in the second?

Comment: In the first case you have a list of ists, the second is a list of `ndarray`.  The second brings `numpy's` memory managment into play.  `np.zeros`, for large fresh arrays, asks the OS for memory, so it also has to take of returning it, or putting it in it's own 'free speac'  That `numpy` memory management isn't as transparent as base python/s.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, so I assume there is no way I can manually delete `numpy` arrays like I could do with lists, right?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks, so I assume there is no way I can manually delete `numpy` arrays like I could do with lists, right?

Comment: @maximus_ow you **didn't manually delete the list**. The reference count went to zero, and garbage collection handled it automatically. **You cannot manually delete objects in Python**. As to why the memory usage of the *process* went down, that is probably up to your OS. On my computer, the memory gets released with the list of numpy arrays just like when you use a list of lists.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, so it can be different from machine to machine. I ran the codes on colab, so we can blame google as to why it treats ref count of objects differently :) Appreciate your time. if you like you can post an answer so I can accept it